# Int? type in generated Objective-C header

Tags: objective-c, swift

I was working on an app that has a case where I need to add Swift codes as data model. Let's say I create a class called `classA`. One of the data field in this class is `Int?`. However, that data field is missing when I opened it in the generated Objective-C header. It's working perfectly if I declare `NSNumber?` in that `classA`. But it looks weird. Is it able to use `Int?` in Swift and successfully converted?

Comment: Consider to use a non optional.

Comment: I tried, still don't see it in the header. @vadian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Int?` doesn't have correspondence in the `Objective-C` world, as there's no way to represent an optional scalar. `Int` on the other hand successfully maps to a `NSInteger` (reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-ID75)).

Try rebuilding the project if the property doesn't appear in the `-Swift.h` header after changing it to `Int`, in order to re-generate the header. Note that a successful build is sometimes needed for the header to get successfully updated, so comment out any problematic code.

Comment: It works. BTW, it's better you can include reference about the matching type. Thanks.

Comment: For regenerating the header file. The last sentence.